# Azure Frontdoor: Caching as a Fallback for Down Backends

Tags: azure, failover, azure-front-door

In one of our use cases, we are looking for a way for Azure Frontdoor to serve cached content, but only when the corresponding Backend is down. The Backend URL path is fixed (thus no dynamic query params etc) and returns static html content most of the time, but with infrequent content updates happening every few minutes. We want Frontdoor to fetch the response from the Backend all the time, but also cache the last response, and serve the same in case Backend happens to go down. Thus the cached content is used as Failover mechanism for down backend, where the returned cached content might not be the latest but still serves the request with a little stale content. 
Can Frontdoor be configured to serve such a use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can make Frontdoor to cache the response from backend all the time by setting the low expiry value in the cache headers. For that expiry time, the data are cached. You need to choose a value which will give you time for maintenance and well as to have the latest file served.

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: I was looking for a way to use the cached content only when the backend is down, and always fetch the content from the backend otherwise. Apparently this doesn't seem to be a supported use case.